# Controlar consulta SQL desde C# (Rango de fechas BETWEEN)

Tags: c#, sql, excel, excepciones, datetimepicker

Buen día, tengo un programa que realiza un control de asistencias mediante un excel a una base de datos, una vez que tengo los datos en la BD, hago una consulta para filtrar datos por fecha, esta consulta funciona:

```
Comando.CommandText = "SELECT id_empleado, fecha_asistencia, asistencia_llegada, asistencia_inicio_almuerzo, asistencia_fin_almuerzo, asistencia_salida, horas_asistencia, horas_atraso, observacion_asistencia FROM ASISTENCIA " +
                "WHERE fecha_asistencia = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "'";
Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Pero cuando agrego la segunda fecha para filtrar por rangos de esta manera:

```
Comando.CommandText = "SELECT id_empleado, fecha_asistencia, asistencia_llegada, asistencia_inicio_almuerzo, asistencia_fin_almuerzo, asistencia_salida, horas_asistencia, horas_atraso, observacion_asistencia FROM ASISTENCIA " +
                "WHERE fecha_asistencia BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "'";
Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Con la segunda consulta salta la excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puede realizar la consulta cuando no es erro de sintaxis ni semántica?

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví colocando un botón de evento clic para mandar la consulta, el problema es que si coloco una fecha que no existe en mi tabla, superior a 3 días, vuelve a salir la excepción, por ejemplo: solo tengo las fechas 9 y 10 del mes de mayo del 2022, sí coloco el filtro en el 9 y 12 la excepción no sale, pero a partir del 13 aparece la excepción

Del 9 al 11:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Del 9 al 13:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]